# sorting with minimum comparison

Tags: sorting, comparison

Give a strategy to sort four distinct integers
a,b,c,d in increasing order that minimizes the number of pairwise comparisons needed to sort any permutation of a,b,c,d

I think there are 4 integers so 4!=24 , 2^5>24 so we need at least 5 comparisons .
but what strategy I should use here?
can I use Counting sort or BBST or anything else to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

A [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) will sort 4 numbers with 5 compare / swaps, where two of the compare / swaps can be performed in parallel in a hardware type implementation. It's possible that if the two potential parallel compare / swaps are done using 4 separate registers, some processors might optimize this by at least overlapping the compare swaps.